# How to import decimal fields using Feeds?

Tags: 7, entities, feeds

I'm trying to import a decimal value from an XML feed to a Drupal decimal number field.

For example the XML feed source is: 7,6 
Now I want to import it in a Drupal decimal field. So the field value will be the same: 7,6

Thing is, when I import the feed and the nodes are getting created - this field remains empty. Is this a bug or can someone point out what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: [last time I checked](http://www.mathsisfun.com/images/decimals.gif) decimals use a point `.` not a comma `,`. Could that be your problem? or is the comma (7`,`6) a typo in your question?

Comment: No typo. I'm from Europe and we use `,` for decimals instead of `.`. I'm getting the impression that may be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that the there is an issue with how it's interpreting the value especially if you are in a non-English context. For example, in Drupal's terms if you have a decimal value it's formatted like so "7.6". If you are trying to import a decimal value formatted with "7,6" it may have an issue.

If it is a bug, you could try and import and use a module like [Feeds Tamper](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper) to rewrite that field output so that Drupal will import it.

I just tested myself and it imports fine using English decimal notation.

[image: test output]

Comment: Yes, you're right. I used Feeds Tamper to find and replace `,` to `.` and it works fine now. So for anyone with the same problem: decimal fields will not work with `,`. You have to use Feeds Tamper to replace `,` to `.` to make it work. If you still want to use `,` in the field output you can change it to comma in the manage display settings of the field.

Comment: Glad i could help!